# java.lang.Error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) Unity Spine Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, textures

Hi I currently have a problem on a app I made where the app crashes on startup or after the intro video.

I am working with Unity3D and Spine to create a 2D game for Android and IOS.

I have searched everywhere for this problem and it seems that this is a memory problem.

I have tried several things to fix this.

Note: This app does work on IOS without problems.

---

## EDIT

Details

-Unity3D 5.3.3f1

-Spine2D Plugin

-Google Analytics Plugin v3

-Android

---

> **Things I tried to change**
>
> - Changed unity graphics api to OpenGLES2 instead of OpenGLES3
> - Tried different texture compressions for different devices (this worked for some devices)
> - Disabled Dynamic Batching
> - Added heavy prefabs inside the Preloaded Assets Tab.

---

**Stacktrace**

---

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [UnityMain]
Unity version     : 5.3.3f1
Device model      : HTC HTC One
Device fingerprint: htc/htc_europe/m7:5.0.2/LRX22G/USER/release-keys

Caused by: java.lang.Error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR),     fault addr 00000020
Build fingerprint: 'htc/htc_europe/m7:5.0.2/LRX22G/USER/release-keys'
Revision: '3'
pid: 2502, tid: 2563, name: UnityMain  >>> EDITED_BUNDLEIDENTIFIER <<<
r0 00000000  r1 a1c11ec8  r2 ffffeff0  r3 00000000
r4 ba072030  r5 00000000  r6 ba06f580  r7 00000000
r8 a1c11d14  r9 00000001  sl 00000000  fp a1c11d18
ip a0d49fd0  sp a0d49fb0  lr a1076230  pc a0e40e20  cpsr 35312e34

at libunity.000f5e20(Native Method)
at libunity.0032b22c(Native Method)
at libunity.000f2918(Native Method)
at libunity.00402ae8(Native Method)
at libunity.00402b2c(Native Method)
at libunity.007c3640(Native Method)
at Unknown.00004c04(Unknown Source)
at Resources.Load(Native Method)
at ResourceRequest.get_asset(<0x00024>:36)
at ResourceHandle`1.get_Value(<0x0004f>:79)
at ResourceHandle`1.get_IsReady(<0x0001b>:27)
at <InstantiateNode>c__Iterator1B.MoveNext(<0x0044f>:1103)
at <Module>.runtime_invoke_bool__this__(Native Method)
at MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine_Auto(Native Method)
at MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(<0x00024>:36)
at <InstantiateNodeAtNextFrame>c__Iterator1D.MoveNext(<0x00083>:131)
at <Module>.runtime_invoke_bool__this__(Native Method)
at libmono.00021ccb(Native Method)
at libmono.mono_runtime_invoke(mono_runtime_invoke:136)
at libunity.003e0018(Native Method)
at libunity.003dffa0(Native Method)
at libunity.003434b8(Native Method)
at libunity.001809b0(Native Method)
at libunity.00387560(Native Method)
at libunity.004cff7c(Native Method)
at libunity.004d51b0(Native Method)
at data@app@com.000df2e3(Native Method)
```

Comment: How about trying lower resolution bitmaps and/or sounds?

Comment: What unity version? What plugins are you using? If you are using NGUI, that's the problem.

Comment: @Programmer Just edited the question with details

Comment: @JimmyB We were already doing this but it will suffer to much quality loss if we proceed to lower it.

Comment: Can you try this on another Android device to make sure that this problem is not specific with the current Android device you are using. Also, more information I want to know is the version of your Android OS and also the minimum API set in Unity Android Settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found out that this problem was caused by big textures loaded at the same time.

After removing these big textures the game started up without any problems.

So for everyone that has the same problem.

Check your big textures and check when they are being loaded and try to load.

Answer (score 0):

We found out that this problem was caused by using PlayerPrefs.Save() twice at the same time on two different functions, also we had used File.write() at that time.
when we save and write files at a different time, this issue solved.